# 12.10 kernel upgrade to 3.5.0-28 breaks booting into desktop

Tags: 12.10, kernel, thinkpad

I updated my 12.10 installation on a T430 thinkpad to kernel 3.5.0-28. After restarting, it would boot into grub but then hang on a blank purple screen when trying to boot with kernel 3.5.0-28. Booting with kernel 3.5.0-27 worked fine.

Comment: I took your solution and put it in the answer as a community-wiki item so I don't get rep from it.  You can mark that as an accepted answer after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>(Used the OP's solution that they posted in their question and made it an answer)</sub>

When I booted into kernel 3.5.0-27, I looked at `apt-get` and saw that the package `linux-signed-image-generic` had been held back. After upgrading `linux-signed-image-generic` by running `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` and restarting, booting into kernel 3.5.0-28 works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to boot kernel 3.5.0-28, grub didn't launch Ubuntu and hanged on a purple screen. I started to use the kernel 3.5.0-27, it worked for one day, at the next boot, it was also giving a similar problem (hanging on a black screen this time). I solved the problem by running `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`, now the kernel 3.5.0-28 works fine.